# Calling Web api POST (abp appservice) with a NodaTime LocalDate fails to serialize

Tags: c#, .net, webapi, nodatime, abp

I am trying to write a web api using [abp.io](https://abp.io/) and implementing [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/).
Whenever I try to call the POST action, I get

> The following errors were detected during validation.\r\n - The JSON value could not be converted to NodaTime.LocalDate.

I have configured NodaTime correctly in the module, I also tested it in a conventional .net 5 web api and is working correctly.

Here is my config:

```
private void ConfigureNodaSerialization()
    {
        Configure<JsonSerializer>(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
            //options.Converters.Add(NodaConverters.LocalDateConverter);
        });
    }
```

I am using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet

I have also tried NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson to no avail, same results.

..and here is the appservice:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class NodaTestAppService : TestAppService, INodaTestAppService
{
    public Task PostNodaTest([FromBody]NodaTestDto dto)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task GetNodaTest(NodaTestDto dto)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The GET is working fine, problem is with POST.

This is the dto:

```
public class NodaTestDto
{
    public LocalDate Date { get; set; }
    public string NodaString { get; set; }
}
```

I suspect the problem is with Abp serialization.

I have my test solution on github [here](https://github.com/evrame/Noda.Test).

This is the curl for my attempted request:

> curl -X 'POST' 
> 'https://localhost:44333/api/app/noda-test/noda-test' 
> -H 'accept: */*' 
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
> -H 'RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8N-JsQhR2mhIqO-RkZtn61KwWgiFfjD60I0EMa07QTooLF9dC8LPmQEDtTws8MpTUtl8b0gtuE-NAiBAXxHEu8IyU8-4w0MfVB4IeZTRsWwXIgzc7pQYReLYnV1IVp0icR5Aj-fMvBqRyvPaNTgVJBc' 
> -d '{
> "date": "1991-08-28",
> "nodaString": "string"
> }'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/3e789ec03d78ff4bb7a2d933009e7fff84cf78af/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/AbpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L82) of ABP shows that `Newtonsoft.Json` is being configured upon  `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions` (instead of `JsonSerializer`):

```
services.Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(jsonOptions => { 
    // configuration settings go here.
}
```

You might want to do in a similar way using `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet`.

```
private void ConfigureNodaSerialization(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    context.Services.Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
    });
}
```

I use the below package reference.

```
<PackageReference Include="NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet" Version="3.0.0" />
```

---

**UPDATE**

The [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Migration-Guides/Abp-4_0#moved-to-system-text-json) states that ABP is using a hybrid approach using `System.Text.Json` and falling back to `Newtonsoft.Json` for unsupported types; it shows how you can keep using `Newtonsoft.Json` for specific classes or all over the place.

I took the approach to only use `Newtonsoft.Json` for the `NodaTestDto` class, together with the `NodaTime` configuration shown above.

Your `ConfigureNodaSerialization` method within your `TestHttpApiHostModule` should look like below.

```
private void ConfigureNodaSerialization()
{
    // Use Newtonsoft.Json for NodaTestDto.
    Configure<AbpSystemTextJsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(NodaTestDto));
    });
    
    // Configure Nodatime (de)serialization.
    Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(jsonOptions =>
    {
        jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
    });
}
```

Now, when posting a `{ "date": "1991-08-28", "nodaString": "string" }` `json` payload using the `Swagger` UI, your `NodaTestAppService` receives a valid `LocalDate` instance:

[image]

Comment: Sadly it is giving me the same result of not being able to serialize.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been stuck for more than two weeks!